# #1054 - Unknown column 'max.ACCESS_DATE_TIME' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

Why doesn't this work?

```
SELECT `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION` 
FROM `user_log`, `user_log_max` as max
WHERE max.`USER_NAME` = `user_log`.`USER_NAME` AND max.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` = `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`
```

I get the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'max.ACCESS_DATE_TIME' in 'where clause'
```

I have tried taking out the alias:

```
SELECT `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION` 
FROM `user_log`, `user_log_max`
WHERE `user_log_max`.`USER_NAME` = `user_log`.`USER_NAME` AND `user_log_max`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` = `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`
```

and this error ->

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'user_log_max.ACCESS_DATE_TIME' in 'where clause'
```

It's taking out the tick marks...why?

EDIT:

```
user_log_max:
USER_NAME        varchar(20)      
ACCESS_DATE_TIME timestamp
```

user_log contains the same column, plus a few more including COMPUTER_NAME and LOCATION

user_log_max contains all the data from issuing this query on user_log

```
SELECT `USER_NAME`, MAX(`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`) FROM `user_log
GROUP BY `USER_NAME`
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is select columns withing a MAX...GROUP BY other than what is in my GROUP BY.

EDIT 2:

Here is how I'm creating user_log_max ->

```
 CREATE TABLE `user_log_max`
SELECT `USER_NAME`, MAX(`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`) FROM `user_log`
GROUP BY `USER_NAME`
```

Comment: are you sure table `user_log_max` contains `ACCESS_DATE_TIME`?

Comment: Don't worry about the backticks not showing in the error message. We need to see the table structure.

Comment: Hmm, show the actual `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_log_max` output. I wonder if that column has more to its name than realized, like a trailing space.

Comment: *Essentially what I'm trying to do is select columns withing a MAX...GROUP BY other than what is in my GROUP BY.*
 Please show the actual query you are running. Your examples are growing increasingly poor.

Comment: @hacket see my answer below - your max aggregate column has no alias when you create the table, so its name isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I am not sure what you mean. I tried issuing it with SHOW in front, and it came back with a syntax error.

Comment: @hacket Now that we see how you created the table (dynamically) it isn't relevant anymore. But if you just issued `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_log_max;`, without the rest of the query that built it, we would see the full table structure, keys, indices, etc.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski oh, I see....I'll tuck that away. Thank you for your help, this looks to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CREATE TABLE` query, you must supply an alias for the `MAX()` aggregate column:

```
 CREATE TABLE `user_log_max`
   SELECT
     `USER_NAME`, 
      /* Alias this calculated value as ACCESS_DATE_TIME */
      MAX(`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`) AS `ACCESS_DATE_TIME` 
   FROM `user_log`
   GROUP BY `USER_NAME`
```

The way you had done it, the column name should be something like the whole string `MAX(ACCESS_DATE_TIME)`, which is obviously very confusing.

Now, you can query it as you attempted to do:

```
/* The column ACCESS_DATE_TIME now exists in user_log_max, so this will work */
SELECT `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION` 
FROM `user_log`, `user_log_max`
WHERE `user_log_max`.`USER_NAME` = `user_log`.`USER_NAME` AND `user_log_max`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` = `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `where` clause to `on`

```
SELECT `user_log`.`COMPUTER_NAME`, `user_log`.`LOCATION` 
FROM `user_log`, `user_log_max`
ON `user_log_max`.`USER_NAME` = `user_log`.`USER_NAME` AND `user_log_max`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME` = `user_log`.`ACCESS_DATE_TIME`;
```